# Upgrading Spring Version to 5 with Apache Orchestra

Tags: java, spring, apache, myfaces, orchestra

We are trying to upgrade the spring version to 5 from 4.2 in an existing project. In this project we have apache orchestra dependency which we are using for creating a custom conversation scope. After making the version changes, we can launch the application but we are getting some error at the places where we use the custom scope. Please see the exception below :

> 2017-12-13 15:36:58,169 INFO  [][as] JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.9.GA (AS 7.5.9.Final-redhat-2) started in 69940ms - Started 696 of 753 services (84 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
>   2017-12-13 15:37:04,421 ERROR [][AbstractSpringOrchestraScope] Exception while accessing bean 'scopedTarget.navigationBean'
>   2017-12-13 15:37:04,422 SEVERE [][application] Error Rendering View[//login/login.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /templates/baseLayout.xhtml @24,54 rendered="#{navigationBean.loggingJSErrors}": org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.navigationBean' defined in file [C:\dev\workspaces********Web\target\classes\com********\managedbeans\navigation\NavigationBean.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory required for resolving interceptor names
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
>       at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:415)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1772)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1781)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:452)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.****.****.web.filter.MDCServletFilter.doFilter(MDCServletFilter.java:43)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at com.****.****.web.filter.ResponseHeaderServletFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderServletFilter.java:37)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420)
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Our server is JBoss EAP 6.4.9.GA.**

**Spring version : 5.0.2.RELEASE**

**myfaces-orchestra-core20 version 1.5**

This is how we define the custom scope :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="conversation.manual">
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.conversation.spring.SpringConversationScope" >
                    <!-- No timeout value should be specified as this is not extended through 
                        activity -->
                </bean>
            </entry>

            <entry key="conversation.access">
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.conversation.spring.SpringConversationScope">
                    <!-- No timeout value should be specified as this is not extended through 
                        activity -->
                    <property name="lifetime" value="access" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks